# If there are less than 5 visible, I want to make the button invisible

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want the button to be invisible when there are less than length (5) buttons visible.

It is outputting 5 each through `visible` state.

on the detail page
But I would like to display the buttons invisible if there are fewer than 5 outputs.

But in my code now, when there are less than 5 buttons, the button is created and the button disappears only when the button is clicked.

When rendering, I want to make the buttons invisible when there are less than 5, but how should I write the code?

I want to hide the button when there are less than 5 visible

It works properly.
However, when there are less than 5, the button disappears when the button is clicked.

However, if there are less than 5, the button disappears when the button is clicked. But what if, when rendering the page, there are less than 5 visible? I want to make the button null on rendering so it is invisible even if it's not clicked.
For reference, 5 `visible` is made visible in

.
`{All.displayText} has set` useState(5)' so that 5 `visible` are visible.
And if `visible == 5` , all lengths are printed.

`ProductDetail.allergies.length`
When this value is less than 5, I think you can set it as visible setState, but I don't know how to do it.

```
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(5);
const [expanded, setexpanded ] = useState(false);

const showMore = () => {
  if (visible === 5) {
    setVisible(ProductDetail.allergies.length);
    setexpanded(true);
  } else {
    setVisible(5);
    setexpanded(false);
  } 
}

return (
  {ProductDetail && ProductDetail.allergies?.length 
  ? ProductDetail.allergies.slice(0, visible).map(All => (
    <li key={All.id}> 
      {All.displayText} 
    </li>

    <ButtonBox>
      {visible >= 4
        ? <button type="button" onClick={showMore}>
            {expanded 
              ? (<div><span>close</span><img src={Vector190}/></div>) 
              : (<div><span>more</span><img src={Vector189}/></div>)
            }  
          </button>
        : null
      }
    </ButtonBox>
)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the condition then be `visible >= 5` if you want to "hide" the button when ***not*** greater than or equal to 5, i.e. when `visible <5`?

Comment: @DrewReese I fixed it, but I don't know how to make it invisible in less than 5.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "invisible"? Do you simply want to render `null` like the current code is doing, or do you want *some* CSS to hide the elements? Think you could create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: @DrewResse I want to hide the button when there are less than 5 visible.

Comment: Less than 5 what visible? Or do you really just mean when `visible` variable value is less than `5`? Is this not what the `visible >= 5 ? button : null` business handles? It's hard to understand what you say isn't working and what you are expecting the given code to do. Can you provide us a more complete code example that we can reproduce ourselves, or provide a codesandbox that does?

Comment: @DrewResse I want to make the button invisible when there are less than 5 visible.
`visible >= 5 button :null` In this way, the buttons are activated even for those with 2-3 visible.
But when I click the button, the button disappears.
When rendering, the button should disappear at the same time.

Comment: You need to provide more code and context. The code you've shared should conditionally render the button based on the value of `visible` so if the code isn't working as expected then there's an issue with setting the `visible` state and when you think it's updated.

Comment: @DrewResse It works properly.
However, if there are less than 5, the button disappears when the button is clicked. But what if, when rendering the page, there are less than 5 visible? I want to make the button null on rendering so it is invisible even if it's not clicked.

Comment: @DrewReese For reference, 5 `visible` is made visible in <li>.

Comment: @DrewReese And if `visible == 5` , all lengths are printed.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

```
  <ButtonBox> 
  { 
    visible < ProductDetail.allergies?.length 
      ? <button type="button" onClick={showMore}>
          {expanded 
            ? (<div><span>close</span><img src={Vector190}/></div>) 
            : (<div><span>more</span><img src={Vector189}/></div>)
    }  
        </button>
      : null
  } 
  </ButtonBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is this:

```
return (
  {ProductDetail && ProductDetail.allergies?.length 
  ? ProductDetail.allergies.slice(0, visible).map(All => (
    <li key={All.id}> 
      {All.displayText} 
    </li>

    <ButtonBox>
      {visible < 5 // <- change the condition here
        ? <button type="button" onClick={showMore}>
            {expanded 
              ? (<div><span>close</span><img src={Vector190}/></div>) 
              : (<div><span>more</span><img src={Vector189}/></div>)
            }  
          </button>
        : null
      }
    </ButtonBox>
)
```

Comment: I tried applying the code, but the button is disabled when there are less than 5, but the button appears as null even on pages with more than 5 visible.

Comment: It works properly.
However, if there are less than 5, the button disappears when the button is clicked. But what if, when rendering the page, there are less than 5 visible? I want to make the button null on rendering so it is invisible even if it's not clicked.

Comment: For reference, 5 `visible` is made visible in <li>.

Comment: And if `visible == 5` , all lengths are printed.